# TFS merge branches in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, tfs, jenkins-pipeline

I've tried to merge between two branches in the Jenkins, but I didn't get it. I tried to solve this creating a pipeline (groovy) and run the tfs merge command, like this:

```
stage('Merging between Dev and Homologação') {
        steps {
            script{

                try{
                     bat "tf merge ${TFS_BRANCH_DEV} ${TFS_BRANCH_HOMOLOGACAO} /recursive /version:T /login:${TFS_USR};${TFS_PSW}"
                }
                catch (exception) {
                    IS_MERGE = 1
                }

                try{   
                    if (IS_MERGE == 1){
                        //resolve the merge conflits
                        bat "tf resolve ${TFS_BRANCH_HOMOLOGACAO} /auto:TakeTheirs /recursive /noprompt /login:${TFS_USR};${TFS_PSW}"

                        //build the solution
                        bat "\"${tool name: '.NET Compilação', type: 'msbuild'}\" ${TFS_BRANCH_HOMOLOGACAO_SO} /p:Configuration=Jenkins;Platform=\"Any CPU\" /t:Clean;Build" 
                    }
                }
                catch (exception) {                        
                    throw exception
                }
            }
        }
```

Another solution is to create two jobs (free style) for getting and building development and homolog branches and then create another job, using multijob plugin. There, I invoke the other two build jobs and after that I run the merge and resolve command in the command windows area. It didn't work.

I don't know what to do. I got it easily using git another project, however using TFS likes difficult to do it.

Can anyone help me, please?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the error when you run your script? First please make sure tf command is installed on the CI server where your job is running (check where your job is running and jump onto that machine to check) or check tf.exe command  line located in the PATH (try specifying the full path to tf to check this)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

First, it is necessary to remove all workspaces. After, it needs to clean the TFS cache, as following:

Tfs 2017: "%localappdata%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\7.0\Cache\"
Tfs 2015: "%localappdata%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\6.0\Cache\"
Tfs 2013: "%localappdata%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache\"
Tfs 2012: "%localappdata%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache\"

Finally, if there is a free style job in the jenkins, check the workspace out is correct. In general tab, click on advanced project option button, and then mark "Use custom workspace", inform the workspace in the Directory field.